# How to convert string date in datetime.date format

Tags: python, django, datetime

I want to convert date like Jun 28 in datetime format like 2014-06-28. I tried following code and many more variation which gives me correct output in ipython but I m unable to save the record in database. It throws error as value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format. Can anyone help me to fix this issue ?

Following is the code snippet

```
            m = "Jun"
            d = 28
            y = datetime.datetime.now().year
            m = strptime(m,'%b').tm_mon
            if m > datetime.datetime.now().month:
                y=y-1
            new_date = str(d)+" "+str(m)+" "+str(y)
            new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_date, '%b %d %Y').date()
```

my models.py is as

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 256, null = True, blank = True)
    Location = models.CharField(max_length = 256, null = True, blank = True)
    Degree = models.CharField(max_length = 256, null = True, blank = True)
    Updated_on = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
```

Code that saves to model is like

```
def save_record(self):
    try:
        record = Profile(Name= indeed.name,
            Location = loc,
            Degree = degree,
            Updated_on = new_date,
            )
        record.save()
        print "Record added"
    except Exception as err:
        print "Record not added ",err
        pass
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you also put your code that saves to the model into the question?

Comment: Check whether your `Updated_on` field uses `DateField` or `DateTimeField`. That will affect whether you use a `datetime.date()` object or `datetime.datetime()` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a `date` object, you can use the `strftime()` function to [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) it into a string.

Let's say `new_date` is your date object from your question.  Then you can do:

```
new_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Btw, you can do the same with a `datetime` object too.

**EDIT:**
Double check whether your `Updated_on` field uses `DateField` or `DateTimeField`. That will affect whether you use a `datetime.date()` object or `datetime.datetime()` object, respectively.

Comment: It still throws same error that Invalid Date format should be in YYYY-MM-DD format. Is there any problem with my code ?

Comment: If you're using django, then your new_date object should be able to be saved.  When you print out `str(new_date)` what do you see?

Comment: It shows following output      In [14]: print str(new_date)
2014-06-28

In [15]: print type(new_date)
<type 'datetime.date'>

Comment: What happens when you just save a new `date` object, like this: `date.today()`
If that doesn't work, then it's something wrong with how the django model is set up.
Also, try just using literal strings for your other fields, to eliminate any potential causes for error.

Comment: If I tries to add datetime.now() in model it saves record succesfully

Comment: I see, so it sounds like your model is using a DateTimeField instead of DateField like in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I tried on console:

```
>>import datetime
>>datetime.datetime.strptime("Jun-08-2013", '%b-%d-%Y').date()
datetime.date(2013, 6, 8)
```

There are several errors in the code. So solution should be:

```
        m = "Jun"
        d = 28
        if datetime.datetime.strptime("Aug",'%b').month > datetime.datetime.now().month:
            y= (datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(years=1)).year   #from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
        else:
             y=datetime.datetime.now().year
        new_date =  str(m)+"-"+str(d)+"-"+str(y)
        new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_date, '%b-%d-%Y').date()
```

`new_date` is a date object, so it should be saved to `models.DateField()` without any problem(including format issues).